# how to delete node from interval tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, interval-tree

I have been reading about interval trees on wikipedia. Does anyone know how to implement the `delete` method in `Java`? The link to the delete algorithm is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Deletion

Comment: That implementation does not include a delete or remove method. I did look at it.

Comment: You have been here for a while. you should really know better :/ What have you tries? Where's the problem?

Comment: Why has been it been downrated so much?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose psuedocode for deletion using the Centered interval tree approach (which is where the link you used points to) would look something like:

```
deleteInterval(Node n, Interval i)
{
  n.intervalsDesc.remove(i)
  n.intervalsAsc.remove(i)
  if (i.end < n.value && n.leftChild != null) deleteInterval(n.leftChild, i)
  if (i.begin > n.value && n.rightChild != null) deleteInterval(n.rightChild, i)
}
```